# Declaration of Colums in 2d Array with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, declaration

I have an CSV Data in which I have Data which is a Number, but if I import ist into an Arry in Apps Scripts it will not be recognized as an Number. Its recognized as "NaN".

How can I format die Colum in the 2d Arry as a Float Number?

With following code i do the import:

```
var file_PP = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PayPal.csv').next();
var file_ST = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Stripe.csv').next();
var file_BE = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Backend.csv').next();
var Daten_PP = Utilities.parseCsv(file_PP.getBlob().getDataAsString());
var Daten_ST = Utilities.parseCsv(file_ST.getBlob().getDataAsString());
var Daten_BE = Utilities.parseCsv(file_BE.getBlob().getDataAsString());
```

Comment: You might try setNumberFormat after you load the array.

Comment: It would seem your problem is not Numbers.  parseCsv() returns a 2D array of strings.  Once the array is placed in a Google Spreadsheet Sheet character strings will remain string, number strings will be converted to numbers.  Where does "NaN" appear?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]